# Mostrar por pantalla una variable en un procedimiento

Tags: oracle, plsql

Si quisiera crear un procedimiento al que le paso por parametro la edad de nacimiento y me muestra por pantalla la edad actual, ¿Como podria mostrarlo por pantalla si esta en una variable?.

He probado este código:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULAR_EDAD(VAR_EDAD IN INT) AS

DECLARE

     AGNO_NACIMIENTO INT DEFAULT 2019;
     EDAD INT ;
     EDAD_TEXTO VARCHAR;

BEGIN

    SET EDAD := AGNO_NACIMIENTO - VAR_EDAD;
    SET EDAD_TEXTO := CONVERT(varchar(10), EDAD);

    dbms_output.put_line(edad_texto);
    END;
```

Pero me aparece este error:

```
Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language
```

Comment: Es un error de sintaxis. Hace rato que no hago pl/sql, pero fijate si la palabra DECLARE no está de más.

Comment: si estas creando un procedure no debes agregar el declare! solo CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULAR_EDAD(VAR_EDAD IN INT) AS

Answer (score 1):

No lo puedo probar, pero creo sería así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULAR_EDAD(
    VAR_EDAD IN INT)
AS
     AGNO_NACIMIENTO INT := 2019;
     EDAD INT ;
     EDAD_TEXTO VARCHAR;

BEGIN

    SET EDAD := AGNO_NACIMIENTO - VAR_EDAD;
    SET EDAD_TEXTO := CONVERT(varchar(10), EDAD);

    dbms_output.put_line(edad_texto);
END;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Se aplaude el esfuerzo por responder, sin embargo no veo cambio entre el código publicado en la pregunta y tu respuesta. Es mejor agregar una explicación de dónde está el problema del AP y no responder con solo código.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. De hecho mi solución está mala. La Edité a lo correcto. La clave está en eliminar el "DECLARE" del encabezado pues no corresponde y definir bien el valor inicial de la variable AGNO_NACIMIENTO, lo cual se hace con ":=" y no con el DEFAULT. El DEFAULT aplica creo para la definición de parámetros de INPUT y OUTPUT, no para las variables de trabajo de dentro del procedimiento.